# How to apply images to the tab bar items in Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am trying to build a simple tab bar template using cordova.

I have this code so far which adds a simple tab bar to the app.

```
            var tabBar = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/iOSTabBar");
            tabBar.init();

            tabBar.create({selectedImageTintColorRgba: "255,40,0,255"});
            tabBar.createItem("tab1", "Home", "");
            tabBar.createItem("tab2", "Locations", "");
            tabBar.createItem("tab3", "Utilities", "");
            tabBar.createItem("tab4", "Inspire", "");
            tabBar.createItem("tab5", "Cloud Sync", "", {
                onSelect: function() {
                    alert("Cloud tab selected");
                }
            });

            tabBar.show();
            tabBar.showItems("tab1", "tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5");
```

The result is something like:

[image]

When I try to add the images to the icons,

```
           var tabBar = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/iOSTabBar");

            tabBar.init();

            tabBar.create({selectedImageTintColorRgba: "255,40,0,255"});
            tabBar.createItem("tab1", "Home","/www/res/icon/ios/Home.png");
            tabBar.createItem("tab2", "Locations", "Home.png");
            tabBar.createItem("tab3", "Utilities", "/www/img/Home.png");
            tabBar.createItem("tab4", "Inspire", "/www/Home.png");
            tabBar.createItem("tab5", "Cloud Sync", "/Home.png", {
                onSelect: function() {
                    alert("Cloud tab selected");
                }
            });

            tabBar.show();
            tabBar.showItems("tab1", "tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5");
```

I tried different path as shown above, but none of the tab item showed the image.

HEre is the image path:

[image]

I copied the image in different places and tried, but none worked for me.

Here is the code to create the tab bar items:

```
 * @param {String} name internal name to refer to this tab by
 * @param {String} [title] title text to show on the tab, or null if no text should be shown
 * @param {String} [image] image filename or internal identifier to show, or null if now image should be shown
 * @param {Object} [options] Options for customizing the individual tab item


    TabBar.prototype.createItem = function(name, label, image, options) {
    var tag = this.tag++;
    if (options && 'onSelect' in options && typeof(options['onSelect']) == 'function') {
        this.callbacks[tag] = {onSelect: options.onSelect, name: name};
        //delete options.onSelect;
    }

    exec(null, null, "TabBar", "createItem", [name, label, image, tag, options]);
};
```

I am not sure, what the correct param to be passed in the image field.

Can anyone suggest me the right way of doing it ?

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that the tutorial suggests to mention the / in the beginning of the path, but the image is applied to the item, when I didnt mention the / in the beginning of the path.

Here is what worked for me:

```
            tabBar.createItem("tab1", "Home", "www/Home.png");
```

The correct path for the image is   **"www/Home.png"**   not **"/www/Home.png"**

I am not sure why /www is not taken as correct path.